How to maintain random numbers in a reinforcement learning simulation integrated with simevents in matlab
I am currently modelling a reinforcement learning agent integrated into a simevents system using matlab. My model is able to run, however there is supposed to be a random number generator in the entity server block "mission". If I unplug the RL agent and run the simevents model only, the random numbers are generated randomly as intended, however if I run the complete model with the RL agent, the results always gives the same values and not random at all. I understand stand that matlab rng is deterministic and depends on a predefined seed, how do you think should I proceed to gain actual random numbers for my model? I am providing some screenshots of my model to give a familiarity to it.

This is the line of code I currently have:
% Generate rng1 as a uniform random number between 0 and 100
rng1 = randi([0, 100]);

% Generate rng2 as a random number between 1 and 2
rng2 = randi([1, 2]);

% Determine the type of mission based on each Probability
if (rng1 > 10 && rng1 <= 100) && (rng2 == 1)
    % General Purpose mission with load 1
    entity.Part.Nj = 10; % [Cycles]
    entity.Ops.FH = entity.Ops.FH + 2; % [hours]
    entity.Ops.IntervalFH = entity.Ops.IntervalFH + 2; % [hours]
elseif (rng1 > 10 && rng1 <= 100) && (rng2 == 2)
    % General Purpose mission with load 2
    entity.Part.Nj = 100; % [Cycles]
    entity.Ops.FH = entity.Ops.FH + 4; % [hours]
    entity.Ops.IntervalFH = entity.Ops.IntervalFH + 4; % [hours]
elseif (rng1 <= 10) && (rng2 == 1)
    % Combat Mission with load 1
    entity.Part.Nj = 1080; % [Cycles]
    entity.Ops.FH = entity.Ops.FH + 6; % [hours]
    entity.Ops.IntervalFH = entity.Ops.IntervalFH + 6; % [hours]
elseif (rng1 <= 10) && (rng2 == 2)
    % Combat Mission with load 2
    entity.Part.Nj = 3600; % [Cycles]
    entity.Ops.FH = entity.Ops.FH + 10; % [hours]
    entity.Ops.IntervalFH = entity.Ops.IntervalFH + 10; % [hours]
end


Previously I have tried to set rng('shuffle') but the results has not been obtainable yet.
Other attempts were to utilize uniform random generator blocks of simevents but converting them from signal to an entity to be utilized by the entity server was an issue
I also tried inserting pattern of uniform random numbers inside the entity server with a modified seed similar to this method: Matlab Answers

Let me know should I provide any further information to give a clearer view of my issue.

When you're integrating a reinforcement learning agent (RL) with a SimEvents model, the deterministic nature of MATLAB's RNG can lead to non-random behavior if the RNG is not properly managed.
If you want to maintain randomness in your SimEvents model while using RL agent, here is what I would recommend:

Use separate random number streams for your SimEvents model and your RL agent. MATLAB allows you to create multiple independent random number streams via RandStream.

It should look something like this:
% Create a separate random stream for SimEvents
simEventsRng = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed','shuffle'); % 'shuffle' initializes based on the current time

% Generate random numbers using the separate stream
rng1 = randi(simEventsRng, [0, 100]);
rng2 = randi(simEventsRng, [1, 2]);

% Your decision logic based on rng1 and rng2 remains the same
if (rng1 > 10 && rng1 <= 100) && (rng2 == 1)
    entity.Part.Nj = 10; % [Cycles]
    entity.Ops.FH = entity.Ops.FH + 2; % [hours]
    entity.Ops.IntervalFH = entity.Ops.IntervalFH + 2; % [hours]
elseif (rng1 > 10 && rng1 <= 100) && (rng2 == 2)
    entity.Part.Nj = 100; % [Cycles]
    entity.Ops.FH = entity.Ops.FH + 4; % [hours]
    entity.Ops.IntervalFH = entity.Ops.IntervalFH + 4; % [hours]
elseif (rng1 <= 10) && (rng2 == 1)
    entity.Part.Nj = 1080; % [Cycles]
    entity.Ops.FH = entity.Ops.FH + 6; % [hours]
    entity.Ops.IntervalFH = entity.Ops.IntervalFH + 6; % [hours]
elseif (rng1 <= 10) && (rng2 == 2)
    entity.Part.Nj = 3600; % [Cycles]
    entity.Ops.FH = entity.Ops.FH + 10; % [hours]
    entity.Ops.IntervalFH = entity.Ops.IntervalFH + 10; % [hours]
end


Reinitialize the RNG at the beginning of each simulation step or each episode in your RL training. You can do this by using rng('shuffle'). Since you have already said that you have done this, the above approach may be more effective.
You can also use SimEvents' built-in random number generator blocks as another solution. This may be challenging, because as you noted is converting the signal output to entities. You could bridge the gap by using entity functions to convert signals into entities.
If all else fails, even though it's a simple step, I would ensure that no other parts of your model or RL agent are resetting the RNG unexpectedly; I would debug and verify your solutions to chalk it up to random computer error.

Just double check that the code I wrote conforms to your environment.

Hi, thank you for your answer @lvand I tried the simEventsRng method you provided, and I forgot to mention that my code is inside an entity server, more precisely in the events actions tab. So as I inserted RandStream the output was "The RandStream class does not support code generation." similar to if I insert rng('shuffle'); which gives an output of JIT incompatibility. Did you mean to have the RandStreams line to be inside a matlab script? If so how would you propose for the entity server to access the rng from simEventsRng? Thank you in advance!
